# Is an "Edit Spree" Discouraged for 2k+ Users?

Tags: discussion, edits

I recently earned the privilege of editing anyone's posts on SO. I heard before that editing a great number of posts in one sitting is generally discouraged if the edits are minor, but what about proper edits?

So the question is:

- Is there a limit to how many posts I can edit a day/week/month and if yes what is that?
- Is it encouraged or tolerated if I go ahead and edit posts for 2-3 hours straight at a time?

Comment: Don't go looking for edits. Just edit what needs editing.

Comment: It is pretty easy to exhaust the patience of the SO users that have to review your edits.  Particularly an issue with tag-only edits.  After ~15 of them start pushing regular posts off my front page I'm starting to dislike you pretty intensely..If you want to do mass-edits then be sure to not pick one particular [tag] to do so.  And don't dig up old cr*p.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think people need to review my edits anymore, as I have more then 2k rep. The reason for not picking a particular tag are I guess that these questions then flood the frontpage?

Comment: No, they still do.  Edited posts get pushed back onto the front page of SO users that are active in the [tag].  Which is why the "be sure to not pick one particular [tag]" comment is relevant.

Comment: Well If I edit things that are usually no older then 30 minutes, it wouldn't bump them up by alot, right?

Comment: @Magisch http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.co.za/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html

Comment: congrats on reaching 2k rep :)

Comment: @Cerbrus NEARLY EVERY QUESTION NEEDS EDITING. And what the fudge is wrong with improving the quality of something? If you can't handle extra bandwidth: _work on that instead_, don't just disallow or discourage the use of those features.

Comment: @username: Dude, what? I only said users shouldn't go out of their way _looking for_ things to edit. Just edit what you come across, if it needs improvement.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Why?​ Improvement is improvement. What business is it of yours as to how I found such posts, or what I chose to do with my time?

Comment: 29 people seem to agree with me, so far. I'm not saying it's not allowed. Going on a spree searching for things to edit will bump those posts up the "active" queue. That isn't always desirable.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In general, if you do something that’s actually useful and significantly improves the quality of posts, then nobody is going to stop you.

That being said, you should keep something in mind when you edit posts: Editing them, will bump them in the list of active questions. As such, you should usually avoid editing a mass of older posts simply to avoid them all flooding that list.

As Cerbrus suggested in the comments, it’s usually a much better approach to just edit what you see that needs editing, instead of actively searching for posts that could be edited. Then this will naturally make you edit mostly current questions, which is then perfectly fine.

Comment: So Assuming I just go through the current questions in my favorite tags as they appear and edit them, thats fine?

Comment: What about my second question then, Is there a hard limit?

Comment: Yeah, if you just edit what you see while looking at new questions, that’s perfectly fine. I do that too. Some questions I edit, some questions I answer, and for some I do both. And no, I don’t think there is a hard limit; but of course, a lot of activity will get noticed at some point, so you better make sure that your edits are actually good so there is no reason to stop you ;)

Comment: @Magisch I'd more look at yourself to answer that second one. Are you sure you haven't caught the SO editing and reviewing bug and are become a little too enthusiastic with it? The pile of incoming trash is endless and polishing turds just doesn't help, better focus on polishing the rough gems only.

Comment: @Gimby In the tags I don't frequent I don't usually assume the authority to decide wether a questions content is worthwhile in that particular subject area. If I would have voted to close a question, I flag it as such instead. Questions that don't look initially bad, I usually try and format properly and fix typos in.

Comment: @Magisch given that you try to rationalize your actions I know I'm not explaining myself: I'm talking about you spending too much of your personal (or perhaps worse: professional) time on it which hurts you, not the site. I had to reign myself in too when I started to feel a little addiction to doing edit reviews, it distracted me too much from doing actual work. That's basically it, just a tiny nudge. If the answer is no: keep at it I'd say. SO needs all the help it can get.

Comment: @Gimby oh I have plenty of time, thats not an issue at the moment. I was concerned only on the front that maybe there is Site policy making what im doing problematic or explicitly disallowing it.

Comment: I tend to stop reading on `active` because it has such bumped posts. After the 5th time of seeing a 5 year old post that someone's corrected the case on the programming language and added and apostrophe I get bored. Nothing wrong with substantive edits, but ... a "spree" sort of implies they won't be. But by all means tidy up incoming/unanswered posts such that they can attract the answers they deserve. You add much more value to the site that way, than tidying up some minor faults on an old and answered post.

Comment: Is there a suggested approach to tag-deletion?  If a small number of questions (lets say 20) have a tag that we're trying to delete, I've heard that the way to do it is to untag each of the questions with the tag and it will be automatically deleted by the system.

Comment: I almost agree with this, except towards the end wherein you seem to treat Stack Overflow like a message board or chatroom, where older posts don't matter. All posts matter. This is a Q&A. So: _"Then this will naturally make you edit mostly current questions, which is then perfectly fine."_ Not so.